# How to configure tomcat 5.5 in eclipse 3.2

Tags: eclipse

Can any body plz tell how to confiugre tomcat 5.5 in eclipse 3.2.

Regards,

Comment: You need the JEE edition of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The [eclipse documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html) can.

There is a wizard for creating a new server.  Just follow the instructions and everything should run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

`click tools > preferences > server > add new > apache tomcat > tomcat5.5` and provide necessary inputs